# Linux ssh key to multiple users in same server

Tags: ssh

I made ssh public key and put in authorized_keys to two users where they are in same server.
But one user can access by no password, other still need password.
I can't use root user. So how can i access no password in both users

Comment: How did you add the key? Best guess without more info is that the file mode is too permissive. Try using verbose logging on your ssh connection.

Comment: Could you confirm that all keys are not password protected ?

Comment: On the remote server, for users called `bob` and `beth`, please provide the result of `ls -ld / /home /home/bob /home/beth`. Change the user names to match reality. If the users' home directories are not in `/home`, please change the list of directories to match their home directories and all directories above them. Add the information to [your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/743241/edit)